# Is there any way to fix CORS api calls from Laravel to a nodejs/expressjs client?

Tags: node.js, laravel, express, vue.js, axios

I developed an api in nodejs/expressjs, I was testing using Postman, it works fine but when I test with an axios call inside Laravel it doesn't work.

I get these errors:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.xxxxxxx/api/v1/connectors/mysql/test' from origin 'https://account.loc' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-csrf-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

and

> Error: Network Error
>       at createError (app.js:18565)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (app.js:18449)

warning:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://api.xxxxxxxxx/api/v1/connectors/mysql/test with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

I tried to add CORS in the headers of my API like this:

```js
// token verification
router.use((req, res, next) => {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
...
```

I was testing in online test APIs websites and the call works fine, so now I'm wondering if there is something that I'm missing in the Laravel configuration. 
I realize that the API client never reads the token from the header(only in Laravel + axios).
Could someone please help me with that?

Thank you!

Comment: Really just guessing here but I'd say Axios has been configured to add the `x-csrf-token` to all AJAX requests in the assumption that none are external. You should overwrite / remove that header for this particular request.

Comment: I tried this Phil but then I just create a brand new instance of axios to make the ajax request so isn't using any Laravel default headers. But thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

install the package of cors in node.js /express.js

Comment: I did like this:`
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
But now I get:
OPTIONS https://api.xxxxxxx.com/api/v1/connectors/mysql/test net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED; And I added

Could you help me with that? Thanks

Comment: res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With')
you can try this

Answer (score -1):

The message says that `x-crsf-token` header arent suppprted in the express app. You should add it on your express app. Or disable preflight in cors.

Comment: That fixed 1 message but the cors issue is still there. I realized that Laravel sends 2 requests, one OPTION and the other one POST, the issue is with the POST.

Comment: Yeah actually laravel requested OPTIONS on header, you should accept it, so allow `x-crsf-token` header on your express app. https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options this section actually describe it.

Comment: Actually laravel sends 2 headers: X-CSRF-TOKEN and X-Requested-With. They must be accepted both to allow CORS calls.

Answer (score -1):

As the x-csrf-token is blocked by CORS policy. You have to add the  Access-Control-Allow-Headers in the ***index.php file in laravel*** which you will find in **public folder** .That will solve your problem. Now paste the following lines in index.php file in laravel.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-XSRF-Token, Origin');
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Hey! That didn't work for me, I still get the same error. Do you think that can be something with my Laravel installation? I tested in multiple Laravel installation but I couldn't make it work. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should use jwt token rather than CSRF token because it works with stateless api but csrf token is working with sessions , So it will not work with stateless api

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-Headers value is probably copy pasted from another solution. Laravel requires this setting => `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Requested-With`